# MemoryMeter : Instrumentation is not set; Jamm must be set as -javaagent

Tags: java, grails-2.0, javaagents, jamm

After cloning [jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm) and setting the maven URL in the `build.xml` to `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy`, I was able to install it with `ant jar`. Now I'm trying to use `MemoryMeter` in my project code.

The official GitHub README says: 'To use MemoryMeter, start the JVM with "-javaagent:/jamm.jar"'.

Following this advice and using a javaagent for the first time in my life (in a Grails 2.5.6 project) I've set the following in my IDEA IntelliJ run configuration:

- in VM options: -javaagent:"/home/myusername/git/laser-ygor/lib/jamm-0.3.4-SNAPSHOT.jar"
- in Command line: -noreloading -javaagent:"/home/myusername/git/laser-ygor/lib/jamm-0.3.4-SNAPSHOT.jar" run-app

I think one of those two javaagent settings should be obsolete, but I don't know which of them works, and I believe it won't do any harm to set them both.

Anyway, I'm experiencing: **Instrumentation is not set; Jamm must be set as -javaagent.**

which obviously is caused by [instrumentation being null](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm/blob/master/src/org/github/jamm/MemoryMeter.java#L207).

So, how can I use this javaagent with instrumentation being not null?

Comment: There is a similar question concerning the use of MemoryMeter in the context of an sbt project. Unfortunately, I don't get any clue from it.

Comment: In eclipse, the correct options would be the VM options. Command line is used there for application arguments (the `String[] args` argument for the main method). Not sure if that matches IntelliJ.